# Image can't be shown on OpenCV with Python

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

現在アナコンダにてOpenCVの学習をしております。しかし、指定画像をSpyder上で表示しようとするとエラーが返されます。

使用環境: Anaconda3(Python 2.7.13), Windows 7, OpenCV 3.2.0

試みた内容は下記です。

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import cv2
>>>
>>> img = cv2.imread('sample',0)
>>> cv2.imshow('image',img)
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in cv::imshow, fi
le C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static\opencv\modules\highgui\src
\window.cpp, line 304
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cv2.error: C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static\opencv\modules\hig
hgui\src\window.cpp:304: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function
 cv::imshow
```

ご助言のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 画像ファイル読み込み`cv2.imread`に失敗しています。`sample`というファイル名のファイルは存在していますか？拡張子を忘れていませんか？

Comment: 拡張子をつけたところimegeのウィンドウが表示されました。ありがとうございました。
しかし、表示されたウィンドウ内は指定した画像ではなく、グレー画像が表示されつづけます。さらに常時読み込み状態、クリックでフリーズします。

Comment: インタプリタ上で`cv2.waitKey(0)`を続けて実行すると表示されるかもしれません。OpenCVで画像をウインドウ表示させる場合、スクリプトファイルを作ってそれを実行する方がトラブルが少ないと思います。

Comment: waitKeyを記載足したところ解決いたしました、失礼しました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in cv::imshow
> ```

画像サイズが0、つまり "空っぽの画像" を表示しようとしてエラーになっています。[`cv2.imread`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imread)メソッドは、ファイル読込に失敗すると "空(empty)画像" を返します。

---

[`cv2.imshow`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#imshow)メソッドで正しく画像を表示するには、続いて`cv2.waitKey`を呼び出す必要があります。

> **Note:** This function should be followed by `waitKey` function which displays the image for specified milliseconds. Otherwise, it won’t display the image. [...]